# how to write python selenium code when you face captcha

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

can anyone help me in writing python selenium code in which whenever the captcha apears the bot stop and wait for 10 to 15 mins and start the usuall script again.

Comment: We can help you. What is the code you need help with?